# How to setup a virtual domain name?

Tags: centos, virtualhost

I have a centos machine, currently I could view website on /var/www/html site using 10.10.10.111, and would like to know how to setup a virtual domain name for a local instance, such that I could view with `http://demo` or so?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would either need to setup the machine in DNS, or the simpler way is to put a host entry like so:

```
10.10.10.111    demo
```

in you `/etc/hosts` file